# Matrix addition in awk

Tags: awk

I have a bunch of variables which look like this:

```
(DURATION 1.57) + (DURATION 2.07)
(T0 10) (T1 0) (TX 0) + (T0 12) (T1 0) (TX 1)
(TC 1) (IG 0) + (TC 2) (IG 3)
```

Is it possible to have awk process this such that the result is:

```
(DURATION 3.64)
(T0 22) (T1 0) (TX 1) 
(TC 3) (IG 3)
```

Or can anyone recommend another unix program I can use to do this?

Comment: It certainly could be done with `awk` (as virtually any text processing task in the Universe). The question is whether it's reasonable :). Maybe you know the program which generated such structured data?

Comment: I would create a formal EBNF grammar (it looks quite simple), then generated a processor for this data using e.g. [`bison`](http://www.gnu.org/software/bison/) or [Boost.Spirit](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/spirit/doc/html/index.html) and give it a go.

Comment: I guess this is a homework, so different accounts raised similar questions at similar time (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23532337/awk-or-sed-sum-similar-value-in-rows) Then the teacher later will change the plus `+` to other operators.

Comment: @BMW Sorry to disappoint you but this is not for homework ;-). I tried to write down a more general description of my problem but the example above was much clearer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one way to do it:

```
awk '{
    gsub(/[()+]/, "")
    for(nf=1; nf<=NF; nf+=2) {
        flds[$nf] += $(nf+1)
    }
    sep = ""
    for(fld in flds) {
        printf "%s(%s %g)", sep, fld, flds[fld]
    sep = FS
    }
    print "";
    delete flds
}' file
(DURATION 3.64)
(T0 22) (T1 0) (TX 1)
(TC 3) (IG 3)
```

- We remove the special characters `()+` using `gsub()` function.
- We iterate over all fields adding variables to an array and adding the values
- We iterate over the array, printing them in our desired format.
- Add a new line after we are done printing
- Delete the array so that we can re-use it on next line
- **Note:** The order of lines will be same as input file but using the `in` operator for our `for loop` the variables on each line may appear in random order.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the solution and the explanation! Only issue I have is that floating point values get rounded to nearest integer. Any idea how to work around that? I am using GNU Awk 3.1.5.

Comment: @Michael You're welcome. Updated the solution to use `%g` for `printf`.

Comment: Thanks, replacing %s with %g does the job.