# awk or sed sum similar value in rows

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I have a file with values such as:

```
(X1 55) (X2 99) (X3 29) (X1 3) (X3 10)
(X1 21) (X3 11) (X1 9)
```

Is there a way to add the values by the `Xn` names in each row:

```
(X1 58) (X2 99) (X3 39)
(X1 30) (X3 11)
```

I'm not sure which is best to use, awk, sed or...? I tried this:

```
awk '{for (i=t=0;i<NF;) t+=$++i; $0=t}1' file

196
41
```

It obviously sums all values together, so maybe it's a bit more complex.

Comment: Use the first element of the () pair as key (array index) and the second element as the thing you increment with. awk is the way. Can you take it from here or do I need to show you?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$ awk '{
    for (i=1;i<NF;i+=2) {
        sum[$i]+=$(i+1)
    }
    ofs = ""
    for (key in sum) {
        printf "%s%s %d)", ofs, key, sum[key]
        delete sum[key]
        ofs = OFS
    }
    print ""
}' file
(X2 99) (X3 39) (X1 58)
(X3 11) (X1 30)
```

If you care about the order of the fields, there's various ways to keep the original order...

Comment: Very similar answer, very similar timing… worth an up vote. How do you get away with not caring about the `)` at the end of each number? Also - I like the fact that you delete the sum after printing: ready for the next line.

Comment: awk sees all input as being of type numeric-string and then figures out if it's a number or a string based on how you first use it. If you use it in a numeric context, e.g. with addition, then the numeric-string gets converted to a number and if that numeric-string had trailing characters (e.g. `)`) after leading digits, those trailing characters just get cut from the end.

Comment: Ed - for that tidbit alone I wish I could up vote your answer again...

Comment: @Floris I'll do that for you.

Comment: I vote up as well, but seems it is ugly with ofs/OFS set, should do it better without it.

Comment: @BMW there's only a couple of possibilities to produce the desired output without adding spaces to the start or end of the line, using a variable like ofs above is as clean a way as any.

Comment: @EdMorton, Thank you, that works. One question, is it possible to make the awk command one line; I'm guessing the carriage returns are crucial to the way it operates?

Comment: order of output doesn't match OP's desired output though.

Comment: @pleasedeleteme - as I said in the answer, `If you care about the order of the fields, there's various ways to keep the original order`

Comment: @ctfd to make it 1 line, add semi-colons where necessary. All that'd do is make it hard to read, though.

Comment: Better way to make a one-liner: put the `awk` script in a file and call with `awk -f myScript` etc.

Comment: I just noticed the uncanny similarity with the accepted answer to the "dup" question - in particular the trick with OFS (it uses FS and calls the variable `sep`). I guess you guys read the same book... Note - I am emphatically NOT accusing either author of plagiarism - just marveling that sometimes there is just a "right" solution...

Comment: Yes, there was no suggested dup question when I answered, this is just an idiomatic awk approach. When using an index, `i`, going from, say, `1 to NF`, then you know if it's the first or last value you're printing and so then you'd typically use `printf "%s%s", (i>1?OFS:""), $i` or `printf "%s%s", $i, (i<NF?OFS:ORS)` to avoid adding spurious leading or trailing spaces, but that's not naturally available with an `in` loop like we have here.

Answer (score 3):

Here you are:

```
echo '(X1 55) (X2 99) (X3 29) (X1 3) (X3 10)' | sed 's/[()]//g' | awk '{for( i=1; i<NF; i+=2) a[$i]+=$(i+1);} {for (keys in a ) print keys, a[keys];}'
```

output:

```
X1 58
X2 99
X3 39
```

I think that's close enough?

Comment: Unfortunately the output needs to remain on each of the two lines; thank you for taking the time to answer - much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I'd go with manipulating `FS` and `RS` to closely match the data. awk's array traversal is random unless you are using `gawk >= 4.0` and set `PROCINFO["sorted_in"]` to specify they method of traversal.

```
$ awk '
    NF{ x[$1] += $2 }
    2==NF{
        for (i in x) { printf "%s(%s %s)", sep, i, x[i]; sep = " "; }
        print "";
        split("",x); sep = "";
    }
    ' RS='[\\n\\(]' FS='[ \\n]' /tmp/file.txt
(X1 58)  (X2 99)  (X3 39)
(X1 30)  (X3 11)
```